# flutter reload page not working when i use provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). The problem in the code below is that I can't reload the API.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData(context);
  }

  Future<void> getData(BuildContext context) async {
    final provider = Provider.of<AppDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final userId = provider.userId;
    await Future.wait([
      getCourseView(context),
      getCourseNew(context),
      getAllCourses(context),
      getRandomCourse(context),
      getTrainer(context),
      fetchTrainers(context, userId),
    ]);
  }


  Future<bool> checkInternetConnectivity() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }

  void showNoConnectionSnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content:const Text('No internet connection'),
      duration:const Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  Future<void> reloadPage() async {
    await getData(context);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //getData(context);
    AppDataProvider appDataProvider = Provider.of<AppDataProvider>(context, listen: true);
    var courseviews = appDataProvider.courseviews;
    var courseadd = appDataProvider.courseadd;
    var allCourses = appDataProvider.allCourses;
    var randomcourse = appDataProvider.randomcourse;
    var users = appDataProvider.users;
    String? tpictureUrl = users.isNotEmpty && users[0].tpicture != null ? users[0].tpicture.toString() : null;


    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: reloadPage,
```

Reload page doesn't work when I use provider to get data from API json file. I try to put `setstate`, another method to reload API, but I think problem is in provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your widget with consumer

```
...
return Consumer<AppDataProvider>(
    builder: (context, AppDataProvider, child) {
        
        return Column(
          children: [
             Text(firstName),
             Text(lastName),
          ],
        );
    }
);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to rebuild the widget or get the value.

1. Provider.of(context) or context.read()

   - `context.read<TestProvider>()` returns the Model without listening for changes.
   - `context.watch<TestProvider>()` makes the widget listen for changes on the Model.
   - `Provider.of<TestProvider>(context, listen: false)` works the same as `context.read<TestProvider>()`.
   - `Provider.of<TestProvider>(context)` works the same as `context.watch<TestProvider>()`.
2. Using Consumer for Specific Widget Rebuilds:

   - Certain widgets can be built without rebuilding the whole content using `Consumer`.
   - allows more granular widgets rebuilds
   - solves most `BuildContext` misuse

If it's helpful to you, then accept the answer and don't forget to upvote.